# Inherit apply method in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have an factory object that defines an apply method to create new instances:

```
object Key {
  def apply(name: String) = new Key(name)
}

class Key(name: String)
```

How can I have the subclasses of `Key` reuse the factory object in a generic way so that I don't need to create a factory object for each of the subclass?

Basically like:

```
object Key {
  def apply(name: String) = new [Some subclass of Key]()
}

class TypeKey(name: String) extends Key(name)

val tk = TypeKey("typeKey")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Well, for this specific application you can use `case class`. Otherwise, you do have to create a factory object, though `apply` can be implemented in a trait:

```
trait KeyFactory[T: ClassTag] {
  val constructor = classTag[T].runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[String])

  def apply(name: String) = 
    constructor.newInstance(name)
}

class TypeKey(name: String) extends Key(name)
object TypeKey extends KeyFactory[TypeKey]
```

Note this will fail at runtime if there is no suitable constructor.